# Compare two tables via the three tables SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I plan to compare two tables via the three table. my query is as the following

```
Select count(*)
from tableA a
join tableB b
on a.A_ID =b.A_ID
full join tableC c
on c.B_ID=b.B_ID
where a.A_ID is null or c.B_ID is null
```

if the count is zore, then the tableA and TableC match, otherwise, these two tables do not match

[image: Table sample]

It takes a long time to run the query. Do we have a way to compare tableA and tableC fast?

Question: How to compare tableA and tableC?

Comment: It is not clear what you are trying to do -- can you describe your expected output?

Comment: Define "a long time". Post the query plan

Comment: Do it as the union of two left joins ending with B?

Comment: If the tableA match the tableC, the expect output should be zero

Comment: `where a.A_ID is null` Your query inner joins A to B on this column, so this filter will never be true. Don't understand why you want to count using a full join - I suspect you have a [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) . Your sample data might be misleading since your tables contain a consistent set of values - you will not "see" the effects of any outer joining.

Comment: Hi Caius, I use full join with tableC to compare with tableA

Comment: Hi SMor, I want to compare tableA and TableC. TableA do not have the join key with tableC. I have to use tableB to connect tableA and tableC. How Can I compare tableA with tablC?

Comment: Hi SMor, if tablA A_ID = tableC B_ID. I can compare tableA and tableC with the following query: Select count(*)
from tableA a
full join tableC c
on c.B_ID=a.A_ID
where a.A_ID is null or c.B_ID is null

Comment: @SMor *this filter will never be true* - I think you might be forgetting that c is outer joined: any row in c that does not exist in b will cause an a:b null set

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**You don't need a `FULL JOIN` here, you can just join the first two tables, then `EXCEPT` the third.**

```sql
SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM (
    SELECT b.B_ID, a.A_Name
    FROM tableA a
    JOIN tableB b ON a.A_ID = b.A_ID
    EXCEPT
    SELECT c.B_ID, c.B_Name
    FROM tableC c
) t;
```

Note that `EXCEPT` implies `DISTINCT` so if you want the number of rows extra in `table_A` then you need to use `WHERE NOT EXISTS`

```sql
SELECT b.B_ID, a.A_Name
FROM tableA a
JOIN tableB b ON a.A_ID = b.A_ID
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1
    FROM tableC c
    WHERE c.B_ID = b.B_ID AND c.B_Name = a.A_Name
);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to find rows that are in one table but not the other you can use the EXCEPT union in standard SQL

```
-- Show in A not in B
SELECT * FROM TableA EXCEPT SELECT * FROM TableB

-- Show in A not in C
SELECT * FROM TableA EXCEPT SELECT * FROM TableC

-- Show in B not in A
SELECT * FROM TableB EXCEPT SELECT * FROM TableA

-- Show in B not in C
SELECT * FROM TableB EXCEPT SELECT * FROM TableC

-- Show in C not in A
SELECT * FROM TableC EXCEPT SELECT * FROM TableA

-- Show in C not in B
SELECT * FROM TableC EXCEPT SELECT * FROM TableB
```

Comment: Hi Hogan, I just want to compare tableA and TableC. TableB is join condition between tableA and tableC

Comment: So by compare you want to see what records are in A but can't join via B to any records in C and see what records in C don't have anything that join to them?